# Download file of content-type octet-stream using restTemplate

Tags: java, spring, rest, resttemplate

In my application, I'm receiving a file from an API response whose `Content-Type` is `application/octet-stream`.

I'm trying to return this file to the front end as `ResponseEntity<Resource>`.

But I'm getting error:

`RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity] and content type [application/octet-stream]`

By browsing some docs I thought of using `responseEntityExtractor` which same as in [RestTemplate.getForEntity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#getForEntity-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.util.Map-).

**My code:**

```
RequestCallback requestCallback = request -> {
HttpHeaders headers1 = request
        .getHeaders();
headers1.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + template.getAccessToken());
headers1
        .setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, MediaType.ALL));
};

ResponseExtractor<ResponseEntity<Resource>> responseExtractor = template.responseEntityExtractor(ResponseEntity.class);
template.execute(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestCallback, responseExtractor, uriVariables);
```

What is understood is by setting `setAccept` in the request callback we are letting `restTemplate` know what type of content to expect, and `responseEntityExtractor()` will return `ResponseExtractor<ResponseEntity<T>>`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
ResponseExtractor<ResponseEntity<Resource>> responseExtractor = template.responseEntityExtractor(ResponseEntity.class);
```

try this to return `byte[]` in controller method:

```
ResponseExtractor<ResponseEntity<byte[]>> responseExtractor = template.responseEntityExtractor(byte[].class);
ResponseEntity<byte[]> results = template.execute(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestCallback, responseExtractor, uriVariables);
return results.getBody();
```

or this to return `ResponseEntity<Resource>`:

```
ResponseExtractor<ResponseEntity<byte[]>> responseExtractor = template.responseEntityExtractor(byte[].class);
ResponseEntity<byte[]> results = template.execute(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestCallback, responseExtractor, uriVariables);

ByteArrayResource byteArrayResource = new ByteArrayResource(results.getBody());
return new ResponseEntity<Resource>(byteArrayResource, null, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Why are we calling `template.responseEntityExtractor(byte[].class)` twice?

Comment: Thanks for catching that, that was a paste error, the 2nd line should have been template.execute (corrected above)

Comment: :) Guessed so. Thanks.